# Sort Address (Uniswap v2)

Tags: javascript, uniswap, ethers.js

I am using ethers.js. I am trying to create a filter and listen to the `PairCreated` event.

The indexed parameters are `token0, token1`.

I am trying to take `WETH` and a custom token and sort them so that I can pass it to my filter.

```
var token0, token1; // init Vars
const WETH = "0xd0A1E359811322d97991E03f863a0C30C2cF029C" // WETH Kovan Network
const tokenA = "0xe12A7BE0e1637a9ab3A137E0Aa114318aCb58BCd" // Token on my Kovan Fork

if (bigNumber(WETH) < bigNumber(tokenA)) {
   token0 = tokenA; token1 = tokenB;
   console.log('token0 is WETH');
} else {
   token0 = tokenB; token1 = tokenA;
   console.log('token0 is tokenA');
}
const filter = eth.factory.filters.PairCreated(
  token0, // address indexed token0
  null,  // address indexed token1 
  null, // address pair
  null // uint
); // Filter for Pair Created

function bigNumber(data) { return ethers.BigNumber.from(data); }
```

The above code at times gets the `token0` correct, but how would I get it so that it sorts correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Change :

```
if (bigNumber(WETH) < bigNumber(tokenA)) {
  /* body */
}
```

To :

```
if (bigNumber(WETH).lt(tokenA)) {
      /* body */
}
```

Otherwise you are using the "fallback" JavaScript comparison operating on strings if i'm not wrong, but it's definitely not what you want anyway.

The ether.js [documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/#BigNumber--BigNumber--methods--comparison-and-equivalence) covers everything you need to know about their BigNumber type comparison.